# Orthogonality version of fundamental lemma of Calculus of Variations

Tags: calculus, measure-theory

I have been struggling a lot proving this theorem, associated to the Fundamental Lemma of CoV.

Let $f,g\in L^1(\Omega)$, where $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ open. Suppose $\int_{\Omega} f(x)\phi(x) dx=0$ for all test functions $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ that satisfy $\int_{\Omega} g(x)\phi(x) dx=0$. Show that there exists $a\in\mathbb{R}$, such that $f = ag$ almost everywhere.

I have thought of using density of test function space und constructing the proof via convergent sequences of functions (to $f,g$) within that space finding scalars there but nothing really worked out. Is it even the way or is there another solution?

Comment: I know the answer now. The idea is to use the following theorem from Linear Algebra: Let $V$ a $\mathbb{R}$ Vector space and $F,G:V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ linear such that $KerG\subseteq KerF$, then there is a $c\in\mathbb{R}$ satifsfying $F=cG$.